How can I prevent mac os from detecting when a monitor has been disconnected or changed
I have a switch box that supports EDID, and yet my Macbook still seems to detect when I switch the monitor to another computer as if I had disconnected it.
Is there a way to disable this directly in MacOS and not have it detect any monitor changes or disconnections?

What's the actual problem you're trying to avoid? Why is it a problem that the Mac is detecting that the monitor was disconnected or changed?

@Spiff The problem is that on the DP it is disconnecting the monitor (i.e. noticing that a monitor has been disconnected).  Thats a problem because I don't want it to do that. And it shouldn't be doing that with an EDID connection. It works fine for HDMI with EDID because HDMI's HPD is essential passive (pull up resistor) while on DP it's an more complicated. So yes on the DP it maintains the correct resolution and sync because of the EDID but it doesn't matter because it reacts to the HPD. There is hardware option i'm exploring but it would be nice if i could just keep the OS form responding.
